# Multiple where condition in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is my table structure.

I want to compare the column *property_id* by the column *label_id*.

**Table:** label_master

| id | label_id | property_id | property_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 25 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 | 10 |

I want to apply the condition like

```
where (property_id = 1 and property_value >= 10) and (property_id = 2 and property_value >= 15)
```

I want to check both property_id's property_value of same label.

My expected out is

| id | label_id | property_id | property_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 25 |

Answer (score 2):

You want `or` in your logic:

```
where (property_id = 1 and property_value >= 10) or
      (property_id = 2 and property_value >= 15)
```

Comment: I want only those who satisfy both conditions.

Comment: @DhruvRaval MySQL checks these conditions for **each row**.  A single row cannot have both a value of `1` _and_ a value of `2` at the same time, it's one _or_ the other.

Comment: Can we use join?

Comment: @DhruvRaval Did you even try this suggestion?  It gives you the output you wanted in the question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0536ee/6  I don't see why you'd need a `JOIN` here.

Comment: Not working as expected. Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fca3614/1

Comment: It must satisfy both constion

Comment: @DhruvRaval You changed `id = 5` to have a `property_value` of 15, instead of 5.